# Need help to understand C++ syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, if-statement

I am relatively new to C++. Here is a if statement I can not understand.

```
if ((ObjPtr = NewObjPtr) != NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

What is the "!= NULL" checked for?

Thanks.

Comment: btw, the ` != NULL` part is superfluous.

Answer (score 11):

This assigns `NewObjPtr` to `ObjPtr` and checks if `ObjPtr` is non-null.

It is equivalent to the following:

```
ObjPtr = NewObjPtr;
if (ObjPtr != NULL) { ... }
```

Comment: Remark : the code from the question is a code smell. It should be written in a simple/clear way.

Comment: The code in question is simple, clear and straightforward to any C++ programmer - although I would say there's usually a function or some other expression in place of `NewObjPtr`. The benefits of the syntax are more easily seen in a while loop.

Comment: @Klaim: I agree, but it seems that OP is not the author =)

Comment: Thanks. your guys are great help.

Comment: vitaut> That's what I assumed but I wanted to point it to be sure this is considered like a code smell.

eq> I don't agree : it combines several expressions, one being an assignement and all written in a way that makes the order of execution less obvious. It's simply error prone : errors can easily hide behind this kind of code. 
A while loop can be written with more statements to do the same and be more clear. Even the compiler will not make a difference because of obvious optimizations.
Anyway, the worst thing is that it's a way of writting code that makes other readers "stop" while reading.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ an expression like `myVar = 5` would return 5.
So basically this syntax is checking if NewObjPtr is not NULL.

You could say *the value of an assignment is passed on to the left*.

Comment: did you mean "assignment" instead of "assertion"?

Comment: What? Is this supposed to be some kind of hybrid between C++ and `<unnamed-scripting-language-which-uses-lots-of@'s>`? And what do assertions have to do with anything?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Shouldn't stay up so late.

Answer (score 1):

Every operand in C(C++) returns the result of the operation. For the '=' operator the result is the value assigned. So, the checking if for NULLness of ObjPrt and NewObjPrt.